# Объясните,пожалуйста,функцию malloc

Tags: c, память, malloc

Есть код,к примеру ,который снизу.При выводе размера от массива "a",его размер никак не меняется в строчке `a = (int*)malloc(4 * 5);`
Что с ней я вывожу 4байта,что без нее 4 байта,хотя,если задавать массив статично,a[20],то размер в конце будет 80.Как правильно использовать функцию malloc?

P.S.Цикл я писал,чтобы попробовать заполнить массив,думал что-то помеянется,а нет,все также

P.S.S. изначально строка `a = (int*)malloc(4 * 5);` была `a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*b);` Тоже не помогло

```
int main()
    {
        system("chcp 1251 >> NUL");
        srand(time(NULL));
        int b = 20;
        int* a;
        a = (int*)malloc(4 * 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
             a[i] = rand();
        }
        printf("%i", sizeof(a));
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте я лучше объясню `sizeof`.

`sizeof(a)` дает вам размер (количество памяти) выделяемой *для переменной* `a`. Т.е. место, в котором, поскольку `a` объявлена как

```
int* a;
```

можно хранить указатель на `int`. В 32-разрядной программе - 4 байта.

И никакого отношения к тому, на что *указывает* этот указатель, т.е. к его *значению*, `sizeof` совершенно не имеет.

```
a = (int*)malloc(4 * 5);
```

Здесь вы выделили 20 **байт**. Думаю, что в вашей системе `sizeof(int) == 4`, так что вы выделили место для 5 (прописью: пяти) значений типа `int`. А пишете туда

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
     a[i] = rand();
}
```

целых 20. Для того, чтоб выделить место для 20 `int`'ов - делайте так:

```
a = malloc(20*sizeof(int));
```

И да - никакого приведения `(int*)` не нужно - если, конечно, у вас и в самом деле С, а не С++.

Предупреждая новые вопросы... Определить *по указателю*, сколько места выделено - в рамках стандарта невозможно.

Comment: Аааа,понял,то бишь,я все-таки задаю размер массива malloc'ом,просто sizeof выводит указатель,а не размер массива?И если так,то как можно проверить размер массива после манипуляции этйо функцией?

Comment: Я дописал ответ; думаю, теперь все понятно?

Comment: У меня СИ,,но немного не понял про 


"Здесь вы выделили 20 байт. Думаю, что в вашей системе sizeof(int) == 4, так что вы выделили место для 5 (прописью: пяти) значений типа int. А пишете туда

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
     a[i] = rand();
}
"

Comment: Аааа,разобрался,благодарю

Comment: @CyberNoble, sizeof возвращает размер объекта (в широком смысле), либо размер типа, в зависимости от параметра. Размер в байтах.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(a)` - размер **указателя**, а не тела массива.
4 байта в 32-битном окружении, 8 байтов в 64-х.

Comment: Если a - массив, то как раз sizeof(a) - размер массива. А если a - указатель на первый элемент массива, тогда да. Внутри sizeof идентификаторы массивов ведут себя иначе, чем в остальном коде.